# Send an Alert for Every Tick

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Is possible to send an alert for single price movement at 1minute timeframe?

```
alert(message=new_alert_message, freq=alert.freq_all)
```

The code above triggers an alert for every 1 minute. Hence, a single minute could have multiple price movements.

Comment: You should consult tick size and average price change on the exchange and the specific token to calculate how often a tick happens, but that is probably more than once a second. Using a HTTP API endpoint, your alert will not even reach its destination before a next alert will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but your alert will be stopped by Tradingview if it fires 15 times within 3 minutes.

I feel like you are using a `strategy`, instead of an `indicator`. By default, strategies are recalculated on bar's close, so no matter what frequency you have, it will be called only once unless you use `calc_on_every_tick=true`.